# Use responses from multiple promises in one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-redux

```
var users = Api.fetchUsers()
  .then(json => dispatch(fetchIndexPageSucceed(json)));

var skills = Api.fetchSkills()
  .then(json => dispatch(fetchIndexPageSucceed(json)));
```

I need to create a redux action which consumes data from both the above promises. I tried using `Promise.all`, but not able to get both responses together.

Comment: How do you want to join the json?

Comment: How did ```Promise.all``` let you down?

Comment: `Promise.all` was sending one by one. I want a collection of these responses.

Comment: Hey @Jonasw I'm not sure how to combine these responses

Comment: @vijith mv what do these promises return and what do you want?

Comment: the first one returns a list of users (array of objects) and the second one returns list of skills.

Basically what i want is a collection like this: 
`
{
  users: <resp_from_users_api_call>,
  skills: <resp_from_skills_api_call>
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
Promise.all([Api.fetchUsers(), Api.fetchSkills()])
.then(([users, skills]) => {
       dispatch(fetchIndexPageSucceed(users))
       dispatch(fetchIndexPageSucceed(skills))
})
```

`([users, skills])` is destructuring from array.

Answer (score 1):

Promise.all is the way to go:

```
var users = Api.fetchUsers();
var skills = Api.fetchSkills();
Promise.all([users,skills]).then(function(values){
 return {
  users:values[0],
 skills:values[1]
 };
}.then(function(obj){
 console.log(obj.skills);
});
```